# Using Same variable For Processing

Tags: java

```
public ArrayList PreProcessingBean(StringBuffer rawTextIn, GlobalVariable objGlobalVariable_)
{
    StringBuffer PPTextOut = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer PPTextTemp = new StringBuffer();
    System.out.println("\n\nINPUT TO PP BEAN\n" + rawTextIn);    
    CleaningAtFirstLevel cleanRawText = new CleaningAtFirstLevel(rawTextIn); 
    PPTextTemp =cleanRawText.FirstLevelRawTextCleaning();
}
```

I am inputing a string from `rawTextIn` in line 6. I am using `PPTextTemp` variable and in the program I am using it everywhere. So can I use `rawTextIn` everywhere to save memory?
Or this code is fine or I have to assign new variable (`PPTextTemp`)?

Answer (score 1):

`rawTextIn` variable is a local variable and it will be removed from the stack as soon as method completes.

Please follow at least these java code conventions. It will be great and more readable if you write variables in `camelCase`.

Comment: @blackpanther ... sorry my mistake... :) will keep in mind next time

Answer (score 0):

if you find that variable rawTextIn will not change and will not affect your whole code then you can use that variable every where other wise better to use another variable